# How to use preg_match to match everything except numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

Here is my code:

```
//Validate names have correct characters
if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s-]+$/i", $_POST['first']) == 0) {
  echo '<p class="error">Your first name must only include letters,
        dashes, or spaces.</p>';
  $okay = FALSE;
}

if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s-]+$/i", $_POST['last']) == 0) {
  echo '<p class="error">Your last name must only include letters, 
        dashes, or spaces.</p>';
  $okay = FALSE;
}
```

How do I modify this code so that it accepts everything except numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vedran was most correct. The `\d` means digits, and the capital `\D` means NOT digits.  So you would have:

```
if (preg_match("/\d/i", $_POST['first']) > 0) {
  echo '<p class="error">Digits are not allowed, please re-enter.</p>';
  $okay = FALSE;
}
```

The above means... If you find any digit... do your error. aka: allow everything except digits.

HOWEVER... I believe you need to re-think your idea to allow "Everything Except digits."  You typically don't want the user to enter Quotes or Special ACII Characters, but it appears you want them to be able to enter `-!@#$%^&*()_+=|}{\][:;<>?,./~`

That seems like a long list, but compared to the complete list of possible characters, it isn't that long.  So even though it seems like more work, you might want to do that:

```
if (preg_match("/[^-~`!@#$%^&*()+={}|[]\:;<>?,.\w]/i", $_POST['first']) > 0) {
echo '<p class="error">ASCII and Quotes are not accepted, please re-enter.</p>';
$okay = FALSE;
}
```

Neither one of these have the Beginning/End-Line special characters, because you are looking anywhere in the string for any occurance of (or not of) these checks.

I changed the comparison operator to (if greater than) because we aren't looking for the lack of something required to throw an error anymore, we are looking for the existence of something bad to throw an error.

Also, I took the underscore out of the last regex there... because the Word Character (\w) includes digits, letters, and underscores.  Lastly, the dash in the character-class has to be either FIRST or LAST in the list, or it sometimes throws errors or is accidentally mistaken as a range character.

Comment: Thank you for your help. preg_match is new to me, so I'm trying to understand the syntax better. I have a guide, but I wasn't sure how to string together what I want and what I don't want. This is very useful to me! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("/^[^0-9]*$/", $string)
```

accepts everything but numbers.

Comment: You're missing `^`, `+`, and `$`.

Comment: @VedranŠego That depends on the requirements. If you want to make sure the string does not contain any numbers, the original regex `/[^0-9]/` is fine. If you need to check whether or not the entire string consists of numbers, your characters need to be added.

Comment: @Arjan `/[^0-9]/` checks that there is at least one non-digit in the string. Not that it does not contain any numbers. With "my" characters, it checks that there are no digits, which seems to me what OP wanted by "accepts everything except numbers". Besides, he used `/^[...]+$/` test.

Comment: @VedranŠego You're correct :) And whether you would need `/\d/` or `/^[^\d]$/` depends on whether or not the string `test1234` should be accepted.